# Sliding expiration for access token with Loopback

Tags: node.js, access-token, loopbackjs

I've installed [Loopback](https://loopback.io/) and enabled [ACL](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Controlling-data-access.html) for a couple of models. I noticed that the **Access Token** is valid for ever, I would like to change this period somehow to, for example, an hour. But even better would be to reset this period when activity occurs (sliding expiration)

I've checked the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/index.html) but couldn't fine anything about this subject. Any help/guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call the login method you can [specify a ttl property in seconds](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/User-REST-API.html#log-in-user)(I believe by default it's 2 weeks if you don't specify). Then you can have sliding expiration by having the following middleware:

```
app.use(loopback.token()); // You should have this already
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Make sure this middleware is registered after loopback.token
    var token = req.accessToken;
    if (!token) {
        return next();
    }
    var now = new Date();
    if ( now.getTime() - token.created.getTime() < 1000 ) {
        return next();
    }
    req.accessToken.created = now;
    req.accessToken.ttl     = 604800; //one week
    req.accessToken.save(next);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. In which file do I have to place this code ?

Comment: Should be where you have defined your middlewares usage, which is usually in your server.js file(the main file)

Comment: Do we need to add any config in the loopback.token ( /*config*/ ) ?